# Web scraping with Excel and VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to extract the team names but i get  the "Run time error 424  Object required" on this line

```
Set lists = html.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-event-item__participants-container")
```

, if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be nice.

```
    Sub useClassnames()
    Dim lists As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim anchorElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ulElement As HTMLUListElement
    Dim liElement As HTMLLIElement
    Dim row As Long
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

       Set ie = New InternetExplorer

           With ie.navigate "https://www.unibet.ro/betting#filter/all/all/all/all/in-play"
           .Visible = True
      Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      DoEvents
      Loop
      End With

      Set lists = html.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-event-item__participants-container")

row = 1

     For Each ulElement In lists

       For Each liElement In ulElement.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-event-participants")

       Set anchorElements = liElement.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-event-participants__name")

          If anchorElements.Length > 0 Then
           Cells(row, 1) = anchorElements.Item(0).innerText
           row = row + 1
         End If
     Next liElement
     Next ulElement

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 424 is an `Object Required` Error. What is `Html` in `Set lists = html.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-event-item__participants-container")`?

What you need is

```
Set lists = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-event-item__participants-container")
```

**Code that I used**

```
Sub useClassnames()
    Dim lists As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim anchorElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ulElement As HTMLUListElement
    Dim liElement As HTMLLIElement
    Dim row As Long
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .navigate "https://www.unibet.ro/betting#filter/all/all/all/all/in-play"
        .Visible = True

        Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

    Set lists = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-event-item__participants-container")

    row = 1

    For Each ulElement In lists
        For Each liElement In ulElement.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-event-participants")
            Set anchorElements = liElement.getElementsByClassName("KambiBC-event-participants__name")

            If anchorElements.Length > 0 Then
                Cells(row, 1) = anchorElements.Item(0).innerText
                row = row + 1
            End If
        Next liElement
    Next ulElement
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I was trying to adapt the response from this thread <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851152/vba-web-scrape-getelementsbyclassname%3E> that seems to work to my needs. It gives me the same error .

Comment: I just tried your above code which is posted in the question and it works for me :)

Comment: yes :) I just replaced `Html` with `ie.document` in the code and it works for me

Comment: Interesant as it gave me the same error. Can you tell me what references have you used?

Comment: `1` Microsoft Internet Control `2` Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Indeed the code is working so i marked it as solved, Thank you Siddhart. Although it works only if i run it line by line with F8.

Comment: I think you may have a slow internet connection. Use `Wait` as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936818/pause-code-execution-but-let-excel-work) Put `Wait 5` before `Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE`